# what permission for the ec2 key is good

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, amazon-ec2

I got a key.pem file and the permission was 664. I used

```
ssh -i key.pem xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -l ec2-user
```

to login to the ec2 instance. 
But an error returned:

```
Permissions 0664 for '/path/to/key.pem' are too open.
It is required that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.
This private key will be ignored.
```

Then I tried 400, it gave me

```
Permission denied (publickey).
```

What permission of the key.pem should be set in order to ssh to the ec2?

Thx in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are error messages concerning different things.

400 is rw only for the owner of the file, which is okay (.ssh usally is rwx).

```
Permission denied (publickey).
```

This should actually come from the server, you didn't add your public key correctly.

Answer (score 1):

```
chmod 600 key.pem xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

It seems pemkey only can be used by yourself but not other guys